# INVALID_REQUEST exception when adding a document with repeated field names to an index with the search API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-search

I am able to add a document to an index when each field name is unique, but when I attempt to update the document (meaning, I use the same code to add it again with the same id and same field names but with one of the field names repeated), I get an AddException with status code INVALID_REQUEST and message "Failed to index [MYID]". MYID is a valid id. The repeated fields have the name, 'purchase_orderDate' and a date value truncated to day of month using Field.date(Date date). My Google App Engine SDK version is Java 1.7, and I get the same exception in 1.6.

So my question is, does the Java Google App Engine Search API support repeated fields in documents? If so, why do I get an exception?

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting the exception because you are trying to add a document with an ID that already exists. Search does not currently support update semantics. Try removing the document first, then "adding" the updated version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Will.  I'm able to update documents as long as the new document does not have repeated field names. Also, the documentation discusses updating documents: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview#Describing_Data_with_Documents.

Comment: Hm. Just for the purpose of figuring out where the error happens, if you delete the document then re-add it, does it work?

Comment: I've identified another problem that is possibly related: When I try to search on the field, I get an error. When I search from code I get a SearchException. When I try the same search from the admin console, I get a message, "Temporary error retrieving documents." Here's the query I'm trying: purchase_orderDate > 2011-1-1. I don't get this error when I search on other fields in the same index.

Comment: Another finding: The query **purchase_orderDate = 2012-07-16** does not result in an error but also doesn't return any documents even though I see a document in my index that has that exact date value for purchase_orderDate.

Comment: I opened an issue for this: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7923

Answer (score -1):

Repeated field names are not allowed for Date and Number types.  But other types are OK.